# What is better approach

Tags: php

```
foreach($db->bigQuery() as $i => $d) {
    // more code
}

// OR    

$big_data = $db->bigQuery();
foreach($big_data as $i => $d) {
    // more code
}
```

- What is difference in performance?
- Does some difference in a big data?
- What are the difference in a future code?
- Does exist some best practice?

**EDIT: Experiment**

```
function experiment() {

    echo 'experiment'."\n";

    return array('1' => '1',
                 '2' => '2',
                 '3' => '3',
                 '4' => '4',
                 '5' => '5',
                 '6' => '6');
}

foreach(expetiment() as $i => $d) {
    echo $i.'-'.$d."\n";
}
```

Returns

```
experiment
1-1
2-2
3-3
4-4
5-5
6-6
```

Result: function `experiment()` is called only once.

Comment: Nice if you don't know, you can always downvote .. thx

Comment: You got the downvote because you could have answered this question on your own. For someone to answer this question, that person has to do the work instead of you. Functionally, there's no difference. Therefore, there will be no difference in performance. Information will be buffered internally by PHP so the choice of the loop doesn't matter at all. So, I'd suggest that instead of jumping at some unknown downvoter, you focus on making your question better. As it is, it's really not good. Note: I didn't downvote you. Hope my comment helps.

Answer (score 0):

I prefered to use the second one .... So the calling of foreach and for is every time the same

This little example shows some unexpected thing

```
<?php
    function dotest() {
      echo "go";
      return 4;
    }
    for($i=0; $i < dotest(); $i++) {

    }
    die;
    ?>
```

as you see ... the function will be executed 5 times in a **for** function

**EDIT TO YOUR TEST**

but only executet once in a **foreach** function.

Comment: it is not true "calling of foreach and for is every time the same" see updated question

Comment: sorry for my bad english ... i wanted to impress, that it's for me the same coding process ... to build a variable and then use it in a function

Comment: I think i understand well, see my experiment

Comment: This is a different scenario than the one the OP was asking about. It is relevant to the overall topic, but not directly to the question. In this case,t the `dotest()` function would have to be called each time because the loop is doing a fresh comparison each time round. In the OP's example, the function only gets called once because it is the output of the function that is passed into the loop. They are different scenarios and would be expected to work differently, although I do agree that they are similar enough to cause confusion.

Comment: The repeating value call in "for" example is a known thing and it is referenced in many sources including PHP documentation. But i'm asking on a "foreach" loop by the reason. I don't know the background of this function in PHP. I did some search, but i don't found anything about this, only measurement of speed, which is not relevant.